Why does the startupCompilationBaselineProfiles test fail with IllegalStateException on my OPPO A53 (Android 12)?
I'm running the following benchmark test on an Android 12 ColorOS 12.1 OPPO A53 device:
package com.google.baselineprofile

import androidx.benchmark.macro.BaselineProfileMode
import androidx.benchmark.macro.CompilationMode
import androidx.benchmark.macro.StartupMode
import androidx.benchmark.macro.StartupTimingMetric
import androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class StartupBenchmarks {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = MacrobenchmarkRule()

    @Test
    fun startupCompilationNone() =
        benchmark(CompilationMode.None())

    @Test
    fun startupCompilationBaselineProfiles() =
        benchmark(CompilationMode.Partial(BaselineProfileMode.Require))

    private fun benchmark(compilationMode: CompilationMode) {
        rule.measureRepeated(
            packageName = "com.example.baselineprofiles_codelab",
            metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
            compilationMode = compilationMode,
            startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
            iterations = 10,
            setupBlock = {
                pressHome()
            },
            measureBlock = {
                startActivityAndWait()
                waitForAsyncContent()
            }
        )
    }
}

On my OPPO A53, the test startupCompilationBaselineProfiles fails with the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to compile (out=Error: Failed to compile !)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.CompilationMode$Companion.cmdPackageCompile$benchmark_macro_release(CompilationMode.kt:434)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.CompilationMode$Partial.compileImpl$benchmark_macro_release(CompilationMode.kt:307)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.CompilationMode.resetAndCompile$benchmark_macro_release(CompilationMode.kt:114)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.CompilationMode.resetAndCompile$benchmark_macro_release$default(CompilationMode.kt:75)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmark(Macrobenchmark.kt:237)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.MacrobenchmarkKt.macrobenchmarkWithStartupMode(Macrobenchmark.kt:436)
    at androidx.benchmark.macro.junit4.MacrobenchmarkRule.measureRepeated(MacrobenchmarkRule.kt:107)
    at com.google.baselineprofile.StartupBenchmarks.benchmark(StartupBenchmarks.kt:49)

However, the startupCompilationNone test runs successfully on the same device. When I run both tests on other devices, they work correctly without errors.
Additional Context:

Device: OPPO A53
OS Version: Android 12 (ColorOS 12.1)
Erroring Test: startupCompilationBaselineProfiles
Working Test: startupCompilationNone

Question:
Why does this issue occur on my OPPO A53 device? Is there something specific to this device or ColorOS that causes the CompilationMode.Partial test to fail? How can I fix or work around this problem?

I don't have access to this specific device so I can't easily reproduce this problem. Please take a look at the known issues.
Generally speaking, some devices do not produce the output required to reliably capture performance benchmarks. If you're already running with the latest version of macrobenchmarks and profileinstaller, please file a bug on the issuetracker for the team to investigate.
